# Take differences between dates within id over a sequence (different rows) in R

Tags: r, date, sequence, difference

I would like - for each id (cpf) - to take the differences, in months, between hire_date  and sep_date on the previous row. For example, I would like to take the difference between hire_date associated with Order 1 and sep_date associated with order 2 (and the same for ids with more than two Order values).

Not all observations have just two order values. Some may have significantly more. How can I write a code that accounts for that? In this case there are more than two rows for a id. So I would also need to make more than one difference.

I would always like to take a difference between a given hire_date (e.g. order 2) and the previous sep_Date (order 1) and so forth. For more than two rows: hire_date (order 3) - sep_date (order 2); hire_date (order 2) - sep_date (order 1)...

```
structure(list(cpf = c(234L, 234L, 245L, 245L, 245L, 555L, 555L
), hire_date = c("10-11-29", "13-7-29", "11-10-19", "13-3-20", 
"13-5-20", "10-02-18", "13-11-21"), sep_date = c("13-4-18", "13-8-29", 
"13-2-15", "13-4-20", NA, "13-10-20", NA), Order = c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

  cpf hire_date sep_date Order
1 234  10-11-29  13-4-18     1
2 234   13-7-29  13-8-29     2
3 245  11-10-19  13-2-15     1
4 245   13-3-20  13-4-20     2
5 245   13-5-20     <NA>     3
6 555  10-02-18 13-10-20     1
7 555  13-11-21     <NA>     2
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the date columns to `Date` class and do a group by `difftime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
  mutate(across(hire_date:sep_date, dmy)) %>% 
  group_by(cpf) %>% 
  mutate(Month = as.numeric(difftime(hire_date, 
     lag(sep_date), unit = "weeks"))/4) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But not all observations have just two order values. Some may have significantly more. How can I write a code that accounts for that? In this case there are more than two rows for a id. So I would also need to make more than one difference.

Comment: @Rnovice You didn't mention the logic to arrive for the output i.e. if more than two rows, what will be the output.  Similarly, if one of them have different lengths than the other

Comment: I would always like to take a difference between a given hire_date (e.g. order 2) and the previous sep_Date (order 1) and so forth.
For more than two rows: hire_date (order 3) - sep_date (order 2); hire_date (order 2) - sep_date (order 1)...

Comment: @Rnovice do you want the `difftime` with `lag` i.e. `mutate(Month = as.numeric(difftime(hire_date, 
     lag(sep_date), unit = "weeks"))/4)`

Comment: Yes, that's it! So the Order column in useless then. I believe it solved for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rnovice that was my earlier solution, but I changed it to yours when I see the order based logic in your post